# Warning: unrecognized cop Rails/

Tags: ruby-on-rails, visual-studio-code, rubocop

I have problems with Rubocop in Vs-code. I get the error

```
Warning: unrecognized cop Rails/ActionFilter found in /path/to/yml/with/cops
...
Warning: unrecognized cop Rails/Output found in
...
Warning: unrecognized cop Rails/UnknownEnv found in
...
# The list goes on...
```

**I run:**

Rubocop version rubocop-0.76.0

VS-code Version: 1.39.2

ruby-rubocop extention in vs code: 0.8.1

macOS Catalina: 10.15 (Problem existed in earlier versions like mojave)

---

**I find** very little about this problem. Basically only thing I found was [this](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/rubocop-rspec/issues/32). And I already have `require rubocop-rspec` in my rspec yml file so no success with the proposals from that thread.

What can I do to solve this? My co-workers will soon start to call me *Mr. Lint-failure*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like rubocop warnings is preventing rubocop to finish. In your version of rubocop there should be a setting called `suppressRubocopWarnings` try checking that if you know that the warnings doesn't need to be handled.

You can do that by typing `cmd+shift+p` and type Open User Settings.
There you can search for `rubocop` and check the `suppressRubocopWarnings` checkbox, restart VSCode and it should work.

If you are using an older version of VSCode without the fancy UI, you should be able to add `"ruby.rubocop.suppressRubocopWarnings": true,` in your user settings json.

It seems to be common to get these kind of warnings if you share a rubocop.yml file across multiple projects.

Source: https://github.com/misogi/vscode-ruby-rubocop/pull/97

Comment: wow!! Thank you. This is it!! Perfect. It works. I can now write premium code ;)

Comment: ... also in addition to this great answer, you might have deprecated cop-names in .rubocop.yml , I did. just run `which rubocop` and take that answer and run that in a terminal to see if you need to do something more to get it to work.

Answer (score 20):

Just in case you happened to copy the `.rubocop.yml` file from a different project like I did, in my case I just forgot to add the [rubocop-rails](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/rubocop-rails) gem, which includes the Rails/ cops.

Install it like any other gem and and require it in your `.rubocop.yml` file:

```
# Gemfile

gem 'rubocop', require: false
gem 'rubocop-rails', require: false
```

```
$ bundle install
```

```
# .rubocop.yml

require: rubocop-rails
```

```
$ rubocop
```

Comment: `require: rubocop-rails` was what I needed. Thanks.